# Loss of data when inserting into firebase database using golang

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using golang and firebase for my project. Recently, I'm facing some issue regarding the  data insertion into firebase, when I inserted data into firebase it is inserted into two nodes they are *task* and *user* nodes by using the below  code

insertion code for *user* node

```
taskUniqueID := betterguid.New()
userData := reflect.ValueOf(m.UsersAndGroups.User)
for _, key := range userData.MapKeys() {
     log.Println("inside task in user")
     userTaskDetail := UserTasks{}
     userTaskDetail.DateOfCreation = m.Settings.DateOfCreation
     userTaskDetail.TaskName = m.Info.TaskName
     userTaskDetail.CustomerName = m.Customer.CustomerName
     userTaskDetail.EndDate = m.Info.EndDate
     userTaskDetail.StartDate =m.Info.StartDate
     userTaskDetail.JobName = m.Job.JobName
     userTaskDetail.Status = helpers.StatusPending
     userTaskDetail.CompanyId = companyId
     userKey :=key.String()
    err = dB.Child("/Users/"+userKey+"/Tasks/"+taskUniqueID).Set(userTaskDetail)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Println("Insertion error:",err)
        return false
    }

}
```

insertion code for *task* node

```
    err = dB.Child("Tasks/"+taskUniqueID).Set(m)
    if err!=nil{
         log.Println("Insertion error:",err)
         return false
    }
```

Sometimes I use the above code to insert data into *user*. It is not inserted into the *user* node but inserted into the *task* node.mainly this problem occuring when I inserted data into many number of users, some user nodes are skipped. For example, I am adding data to 6 different users only 5 *user* node will inserted by this data and one among will be skipped, but this issue is not facing in all time only in specific time. Is any problem related to my code or any network issue? Please anyone help me to solve this issue. I am attaching two screen shot of my db structure

Here is screenshot of *User* Structure :-
[image]

This is screenshot of *Task* Structure :-

[image]